# Powershell - Outlook Mark all mails as read then delete

Tags: email, powershell, outlook, exchange-server

having some problems trying to figure this one out.
For some reason my script is not working as it should.

It should mark all mails in inbox folder as read and then delete them.
However, when the script runs it only delete's half of the .count $emails show...

How to solve this, am I doing something wrong?

```
$outlook = new-object -comobject outlook.application

#Define folders
$namespace = $outlook.GetNameSpace("MAPI")
$pst = $namespace.Stores
$pstRoot = $pst.GetRootFolder()
$pstFolders = $pstRoot.Folders
#$personal = $pstFolders.Items("ARCHIVE")  ##Not working, sadly.
$DefaultFolder = $namespace.GetDefaultFolder(6)
$InboxFolders = $DefaultFolder.Folders
$DeletedItems = $namespace.GetDefaultFolder(3)
$Emails = $DefaultFolder.Items

Foreach ($Email in $Emails) {
#Define folders
$Email.UnRead = $false
$Email.Move($DeletedItems) | out-null
continue
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would suggest using the [MailItem.Delete() method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff863343(v=office.15).aspx) instead of moving things to the Deleted Items folder. From the Delete() method page:

> The **Delete** method deletes a single item in a collection. To delete all
>   [items](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff864247(v=office.15).aspx) in the Items collection of a folder, you must delete each item
>   starting with the last item in the folder. For example, in the items
>   collection of a folder, *AllItems*, if there are n number of items in
>   the folder, start deleting the item at *AllItems.Item(n)*, decrementing
>   the index each time until you delete *AllItems.Item(1)*.
>
> The **Delete** method moves the item from the containing folder to the
>   **Deleted Items** folder. If the containing folder is the **Deleted Items**
>   folder, the **Delete** method removes the item permanently.

With that knowledge I would suggest replacing your ForEach loop with the following:

```
For($i=($emails.count-1);$i -ge 0;$i--){
    $($emails)[$i].Unread = $false
    $($emails)[$i].delete()
}
```

I don't understand why you have to sub-expression the collection in order to enumerate it, but I've never been able to specify a record without doing that.

Answer (score 2):

Do not use "foreach" loop since you are modifying the number of items in the collection. Use a loop from Items.Count down to 1.