# Accessing Outlook Folder in PowerShell 5

Tags: powershell, outlook, powershell-4.0, powershell-5.0

I wrote a script in PS 4 that would read the contents of an Outlook folder, find unread emails, process them, then move them into another folder.  This script worked great until PS 5 was pushed to my workstation. Now, I get the following error:

> ```
> Error while invoking [PROPERTYGET, DISPID(0)]. Could not find member.
> At U:\Powershell\Scripts\Outlook - Process Emails.ps1:214 char:7
> +     $($folger.Items)[$i].Subject
> +       ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>     + CategoryInfo          : OperationStopped: (:) [], MissingMemberException
>     + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.MissingMemberException
> ```

Here's the main block of code:

```
Add-Type -assembly "Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook"
$Outlook = New-Object -ComObject Outlook.Application
$NameSpace = $Outlook.GetNameSpace("MAPI")

$folder = $NameSpace.Folders.Item("Scans").Folders.Item("Results")

for ($i = ($folder.Items.Count - 1); $i -ge 0; $i--)
{
    if ($($folder.Items)[$i].UnRead) # It breaks on this line
    {
        # Do stuff
    }
}
```

Two questions:

1) What changed between PS 4 and PS 5 to cause this?  Nothing jumped out in the release notes for PS 5.

2) What can I do to get my script back up and running w/o issue?

Answer (score 3):

Figured it out on my own...

```
if ($($folder.Items)[$i].UnRead)
```

Changed to

```
if ($folder.Items[$i].UnRead)
```

I was never sure why the extra $ and parentheses was needed, but it worked in the original version so I never messed with it.

Comment: This is interesting. I don't know of anything that would have changed between v4 and v5 to change that; but I think the original version was wrong all along.  May have been a bug that was fixed?

Comment: I actually saw something like this with outlook recently, but I used select -index to get around the problem.

Comment: @briantist, I modeled my original code off of this code found on SO:

http://stackoverflow.com/a/24829429/6679564

Here TheMadTechnician uses an extra set of $ and parentheses, but I was never certain why.